# Are bronzing victims conscious?

Tags: warehouse-13

The bronze statues in the Bronze Sector of the Warehouse are statues made of living people. It is suggested that the victims are conscious of their own being and aware of their surroundings while they are bronzed. However, since no one had been released from bronzing until

> H.G. Wells and MacPherson.

Do we have any proof that bronzing victims are conscious as bronze statues, say evidence from the aforementioned individuals?

Comment: I believe it was actually Artie who first said as much in the episode that the first spoiler'd character appeared...  But it's been years and I don't have the episodes, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Warehouse 13 wiki (spoiler tag because the op used one)

> In 1900, [H.G. Wells] was bronzed at her own request and confined to the Bronze Sector of the Warehouse, immobile but still conscious.

There's an exact quote in 2x01 "Time Will Tell" [[transcript]](http://www.livedash.com/transcript/warehouse_13-%28time_will_tell%29/8058/SYFYP/Tuesday_July_13_2010/368112/)

> H.G. definitely tells Myka and Pete that people who are bronzed are conscious the whole time
> **Pete:** You know, for somebody who's been unconscious for 100 years, you've really held on to some anger. 
>  **Helena:** Just immobile